# Is there a way to change the value of a Jenkins environment variable through the command line?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a shell script that contains a version number which keeps changing based on updates I perform. I need to store this version number into a Jenkins env variable so that all my Jenkinsfiles have access to this latest version number. How do I do this? As far as I know setting env variables in Jenkins can only be done through the UI or within a pipeline. Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Do you want all stages in pipeline where the shell script run can access that version number, or want other pipelines can access that version number.  For later, it will be challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to write version number to a file by shell script, then
read it from file and assign to Jenkins env.

If you want the version number available to others pipelines, you need to ensure other pipelines run on same Jenkins agent as current pipeline, secondly write version number to file into folder which won't be clean by pipelines, the both requirements are not easy to satisfy.

Following approach only enable version number available in current pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  
  stages {
    stage('Init') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          put your shell script here and output 
          the vesion number to a file, like version.txt
        '''
        script {
          env.VERSION_NUMBER = sh('cat <path to>/version.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()
        }
      }
    }

    stage('A') {
      steps {
        echo env.VERSION_NUMBER
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'll need this env var to be accessible to other pipelines too.